# send information from multiple checkbox to array Knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

i have a viewmodel which has information which I am showing on the site using foreach.
This is how it looks.
[image]
When the person clicks the checkboxes maybe 2 of them, the observable turns true, and I have a button which says apply and when that button is clicked what I want to do is get the whole viewmodel array for the two rows which is checked or maybe 1 row which is checked and put them into one array. so I can send it to the database.

So basically I have the HTML here.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: investmentinvoicedatasintable">
  <tr>
      <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.invoiced_total"></span></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.paid_total "></span></td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#" data-bind="if: $data.status == 10,  click: $root.getRepaymentInvoice"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></a>
        <span data-bind="ifnot:  $data.status == 10"><?php echo lang("invoice_table_pay1"); ?></span>  
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"><div  data-bind="if: $data.status == 10" ><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $data.checkedInvoice1"/></div>
          <div  data-bind="ifnot: $data.status == 10" ></div>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Apply

And here is the Knockout js file.

```
 /* Vew model for invoices data */
self.invoicedatasintable = ko.observableArray();
        function InvoiceViewModel(root /* root not needed */, invoice) {
            var self = this;
            self.ID = invoice.ID;
            self.type_related_amount = invoice.type_related_amount;
            self.type_related_paid = invoice.type_related_paid;
            self.ORIG_ID = invoice.ORIG_ID;
            self.Fullname = invoice.Fullname;
            self.status_description = invoice.status_description;
            self.type_txt = invoice.type_txt;
            
            self.checkedInvoice1 = ko.observable(0);

            self.getCheckedInvoiceInfo = function(checkedinvoice){
            if(checkedInvoice1){
                return checkedinvoice;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
        };
```

And here is the button function which needs to check the viewmodel and get the arrays which has the checked value (true) and put them into ONE whole array.

```
self.getCheckedInvoices = function(){
        self.arr = ko.observableArray();
         $.each( self.getCheckedInvoiceInfo(), function (index, item) {
                if(item.checkedInvoice1 == 0){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    self.arr.push(/*only the array which has checked 1 */ );
                }
                
            });
            console.log(self.arr());
    }
```

So the problem is I am not sure how to call the invoiceViewModel to see the checked row information and also how to get only the certain rows that is CHECKED.
the self.invoicedata() is the one that has all the array stored in the starting which is displaying on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha ! you are trying to loop over wrong one . `self.invoicedatasintable` observable has all your data

**viewModel:**

```
self.arr = ko.observableArray();
self.getCheckedInvoices = function() {
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.invoicedatasintable(),function(item){ //use ko.utils foreach 
    if (item.checkedInvoice1()) { //it's a Boolean flag
      self.arr.push(item);
    }
  });
    console.log(self.arr());
}
```

Checkbox checked property makes sure when `checked/unChecked` the observable binded to it gets modified .

sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H7wLT/1524/)

Comment: I used your code, but I get a empty array, but when I just write console.log(item) it shows me 3 arrays

Comment: oops my bad !. updated now @MasnadNihit  `item.checkedInvoice1` is observable so read its value by `()` . cheers

Comment: hey! I did the exact thing, problem is that when I am clicking the checked the observable value still is the same which is 0.. it does not change to 1, so I was thinking should I forcefully change it to 1 ?

Comment: nah ! yoo don't need to do forecully , check sample fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/H7wLT/1522/ . hope that clarifies @MasnadNihit & updated code

Comment: but its weird that the checkbox in the viewmodel is not changing at all self.checkedInvoice1 = ko.observable(0);

Comment: well  @MasnadNihit you might be missing very small detail . i added fiddle up there to show checkbox box binded observable gets modified upon check/uncheck  even if it inside a array .

Comment: yea true, I actually followed your instructions and what I can see is that, the only problem is that when the function is called from the button, the invoivedatasintable does not get updated, thats the ONLY problem :(

Comment: @MasnadNihit can you get me a fiddle with your issue . so , i can help fixing it .

Comment: the problem is that there are so much information on my page, its really hard to make a fiddle :( 
But the problem for me is that this observable item.checkedInvoice1() is still zero when the button is pressed, I even tried to use subscribe like in the fiddle you showed, inside the view model like this self.checkedInvoice1.subscribe(function(val) {
                self.checkedInvoice1(val) ;
                alert(self.checkedInvoice1());
              });
but the checkedInvoice always show 0 when the button is clicked dunno why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113615/discussion-between-super-cool-and-masnad-nihit).