# Get row in which checkbox column is selected - knockout JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, knockout.js

I am totally new to Knockout JS.I am having a table in which one column is input type checkbox.
at the end of html table I have one button as "Add".
Now what I want to do is on click of "Add" button I should be able to get all the rows in which checkboxes are checked.

HTML

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Add Data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: SearchResult">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="" data-bind="checked: selectedArray"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="button" id="addButton" data-bind="click: AddSelection">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Now can anybody tell me how can I get all the rows in which checkbox column is checked.
I have gone through this but this didn't work for me.

[send information from multiple checkbox to array Knockout js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586326/send-information-from-multiple-checkbox-to-array-knockout-js)

fiddle for reference
http://jsfiddle.net/smsharma/u9ts4uvf/

Comment: post your javascript code with what you have tried. Also, you need to mention what exactly isn't working. Is the table being loaded? Is the add click event working?

Comment: yes, Table is loaded with all the data as well as access click is also working.the Issue is I am not getting how to write code to get rows with selected checkboxes.

Comment: Go through the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) and understand what `observables` mean. Then understand [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) and [`checked`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) bindings. This is a basic implementaion. There are hundreds of examples online. Once you written some code and you are stuck somewhere, you can post it here. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: added fiddle for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9ts4uvf/1/

You can create an addItem function, that creates a new item, and adds it to the array `availableItems`:

```
self.addItem = function() {
    var item = new BookItem(1, 'Lorem Ipsum', '$0.99');
    item.Selected(true);
    self.availableItems.push(item);
};
```

But you also need to add a `checked` binding to the checkboxes to ensure that they are checked when `Selected` is set to true for `BookItem`:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), click: $root.toggleAssociation, checked: Selected" />
```

Comment: In my model, I don't have "selected" field.Is there any option I can do it without that.

Comment: You do have `self.Selected = ko.observable(false);` in `BookItem`. That is what I was referring to.

Comment: Actually, I am getting data from service and hence not having that.From service, I am getting data directly into my ViewModel.I am getting an array of book items.Is there any other way?

Comment: Defining observables in `BookItem` is the right way. So when you get an array of items, such as, `var data = [{id:1,name:'abc',price:'0.99$'}]`, you can convert those items into an object of `BookItem` using something like, `data.forEach(function(item){ var bookItem = new BookItem(item.id, item.name, item.price); self.availableItems.push(item) });` If it is still not clear, you can update your fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Well Thanks..I am done with it now.The only issue I am having is I need to update values in selectedmodel only when add button is clicked. fiddle for what I tried. http://jsfiddle.net/smsharma/u9ts4uvf/3/

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Nisarg0/u9ts4uvf/5/ Hope it is self explanatory. :)

Comment: Thanks Man.. This is what I needed.